# VBA Goal seek is setting cells to 0 without changing the argument

Tags: vba, excel

I'm tearing my hair out here.

When I run the goal seek in the worksheet it's fine. When I try to run the exact same goal seek from vba (recorded or coded by hand) the cell I'm supposed to be goal seeking displays as 0 and the variable does not change. F9 does nothing. If I edit the goalseek cell, to force it to recalculate, it displays the original output again - because nothing has changed.

Has anyone else encountered this?

```
Range("G14").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("F14")
```

G14 is a user defined formula with 2 range arguments and a couple of single cell arguments.

F14 is a cell inside one of the range arguments, and is definitely a driver in the calculation.

Comment: Is it possible to post your formulas?

Comment: You're sure the cell G14 contains a formula that's affected by the value in cell F14? (just confirming)

Comment: @hnk G14 definitely contains a formula that's affected by the value of F14. F14 is used in a formula in E14 which is part of a 2 column range (D3:E14) which is an argument of G14. Manually changing F14 results in a change of G14 and, beyond that, using goalseek from the worksheet works just fine.

Comment: try adding a `DoEvents` somewhere in your code. It might help clear out pending events which could be causing issues.

Comment: @Barett I will post the formulas when I get home from work.

Comment: @Barett
G14
`=VanillaIRS($J$2:$K$27,$M$2:$N$27,A14,B14,$D$3:E14,$D$3:E14)`
E14
`=DiscountFactor(basisyears($A$1,D14),F14)`

F14 is a number in percent format. I should also mention that the VanillaIRS function does call functions in a referenced add-in during calculation. This has not been an issue but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Barett I just wanted to let you know that I was able to resolve the problem. In my UDF I had many calls to a simple function using the range.find method to read parameters from a range. When I changed this funtion to "manually" loop through the range instead of using range.find I found that goalseek worked fine. All that said, I still don't understand why using the find method caused an issue.

PS Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it as

```
DoEvents
ActiveSheet.Range("G14").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ActiveSheet.Range("F14")
```

Not sure if it's materially different from your existing code, but might go through correctly.

Also try running your goalseek on the spreadsheet manually while recording a macro and see the auto-generated macro code if something odd is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately DoEvents did nothing to help.

Comment: Oh, and the code that I posted up is in fact the whole result of recording. I should also mention that in the calculation of G14 functions in an add-in are called. These functions have been working just fine in this sheet and background code, though. No issues until the goal seek.

Comment: Just curious, since you are Goal_Seeking to 0, shouldn't the cell display 0? How about Goal-seeking to other values. And how about changing the function to say, `=TAN(X)` and goal-seeking it to reach 1 (so the answer is `Pi / 2`)

Comment: I tried changing the goal to other numbers but the same thing happened. Cell displays as zero, variable doesn't change. I do note that other instances of the function on the sheet that reference the same range also display as zero when I try the goal seek.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I was able to resolve the problem. In my UDF I had many calls to a simple function using the range.find method to read parameters from a range. When I changed this funtion to "manually" loop through the range instead of using range.find I found that goalseek worked fine.

All that said, I still don't understand why using the find method caused an issue.